# How do I return a string from a function that is inside a for loop?

Tags: go

I have a function I have written and I would like it to return a string. I have declared the variable before my for loop, but when I try and return it at the end of the function it claims the variable is unused. I do not seem to have the problem when returning other types. I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong.

```golang
func GetInstanceAlarms(instance *Instance) string {
    params := &cloudwatch.DescribeAlarmsInput{}
    c := cloudwatch.New(session.New())
    resp, err := c.DescribeAlarms(params)
    var Arn string
    if err != nill {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    for idx := range resp.MetricAlarms{
        for _, alarm := range resp.MetricAlarms[idx].Dimensions{
            if *alarm.Name == "InstanceId" && *alarm.Value == instance.InstanceId{
                log.Println(resp.MetricAlarms[idx].AlarmArn)
                //claims this variable is unused
                Arn := resp.MetricAlarms[idx].AlarmArn
            }
        }
    }
    return Arn
}
```

Comment: `:=` *creates and initializes* a variable. If you want to use an existing variable, just use `=`.

Comment: use `=`, without the `:` inside the loop. Using `:=` inside a different scope from where you first declared it will create a new variable.

Comment: Thanks. I missed that since I am so use to :=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `for` loop you have recreated a variable `Arn` which *shadows* the outer variable. Remember that `:=` creates new variables, and `=` assigns to existing variables.

```
                Arn := resp.MetricAlarms[idx].AlarmArn
```

This `Arn` variable is only valid in its containing block, and once you exit the block, the outer variable `Arn`, created just before the loop, becomes visible again.

Instead of creating a new variable, assign to the existing one.

```
                Arn = resp.MetricAlarms[idx].AlarmArn
```

Read more about [scope in Go](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope).

Running `go vet` should catch this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In you code you have err!=nill, change to err != nil

I check your code, I don't see any issue. Once you declared var Arn string, by default it has zero value i.e empty string "".

I tested with (Mac Os) with the following code and I don't see any error. Also I have added in code to print go version and OS.

```
package main


import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)


func main(){

    fmt.Printf("Checking on %s OS with Go version %s\n",runtime.GOOS, runtime.Version())
    fmt.Println(test())


}

func test() string {
    var a string

    for i:=0;i<5;i++{
        a:="string"
        return a
    }

    return a

}
```